# IPv6 Geolocation

Tags: windows-7, ipv6

I keep regular tabs on where my accounts are accessed from, and sometimes search the locations of IPv4 addresses.  I'm now seeing accounts / machines I keep track of being accessed from IPv6 addresses. My preferred site yields no results for IPv6 addresses.

**How do I best geolocate or gain information on IPv6 addresses?**

Comment: Looking up an IP isn't geolocation.

Answer (score 3):

There are several providers of GeoIP data (for both IPv4 and IPv6). For example:

- [MaxMind's GeoIP Lite](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite) - Both IPv4 and IPv6
- TCPIPUTILS.com [IPv6 GEO Location Database](http://www.tcpiputils.com/ipv6-geolocation-database)

However, since many IPv6 users today use IPv6-in-IPv4 tunnel services like [Hurricane Electrics](http://ipv6.he.net/), GeoIP data for their IPs will be useless (since you cannot know the real IPv4 IP of the connecting user).

I've looked up GeoIP info on IPv6 users of one of my web sites several months ago: it was mostly useless. Only a handful of big ISPs world-wide are IPv6-enabled, and most users came from these ISPs, and the rest from tunnel services.

Comment: I talked to MaxMind last month (Dec 2012) and they said they would launch a commercial production-grade IPv6 GeoIP service in 2013Q1. Let's see if they manage that :-)

Comment: The services can't even get IPv4 geo-location right. Apparently, I'm located halfway across the country from where I am (a neat trick), and I know a guy who can't access his bank from his home computer because the geo-location service the bank uses tells it that he is located in some banned African country.

Comment: @RonMaupin: Because of the IP address shortage, this is only going to be worse. IP address blocks get re-sold on a secondary market, and are sub-divided into ever smaller blocks, which are re-sold again. So these geolocation databases are having trouble keeping up.

Answer (score 0):

I've found two free sites serving GeoIP data on IPv6:

http://www.ip2location.com/demo

http://software77.net/geo-ip

Comment: The Wayback Machine says that the first site, ip2location.com, used to have a downloadable database - http://web.archive.org/web/20111012112840/http://www.ip2location.com/faqs-ip-country-v6.aspx

Comment: I tested both using Google's IPv6 DNS server addresses - https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using

Answer (score 0):

http://ipinfo.io has IPv6 support, although it tends be only country level data for most IPs:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/2607:f8b0:4005:800::1002
{
  "ip": "2607:f8b0:4005:800::1002",
  "hostname": "nuq05s01-in-x02.1e100.net",
  "city": null,
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "38.0000,-97.0000",
  "org": "AS15169 Google Inc."
}
```

See http://ipinfo.io/developers for more details.